# How to import a project to eclipse using jcraft ftp plugin

Tags: php, eclipse, sftp

NOTE: I am a new user so I'm not allowed to post images nor more than two links. Since my problem is quite silly I provided screenshots. If you have the time you can download a zip with the pngs here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1517193/images.zip

I'm trying to create a project by importing it with the remote system explorer and jcraft sftp plugin.
The project is a php one but I think this is not relevant

I start by creating a new project (image 1)

Then I right click on the project and choose import to project (image 2)

Then I select remote file systems as my source (image 3)

I have an already working sftp connection (image 4)

I browse to the folder where I have my project and I select it. By doing this I should have everything needed (image 5)

But it keeps saying "enter or select a source folder" and the finish button is greyed out.
I've selected a source folder. It should be the field in "from directory".

I've tried all combinations without success. I should be making some silly mistake because no one else is complaining about this. 
Could you point me out to what I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: 404 on the download. If you fix it I can add the images to the post for you.

Comment: Hey @Kieran thanks four your answer. I lost the file and the screenshots and I stoped using eclipse altogether. I've just seen this comment. Sorry and thanks for your interest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same problem as you did.

Interestingly, I waited for a while (like 30 sec or so), the button becomes available by itself. Probably it was checking something about the source/destination folders on background.

Hope this help.

Comment: same... but I had an SDK in mine and took about 15 minutes :)

Comment: Hi, @Jonson Chen, I stoped using eclipse but I'm going to accept your answer since it seems quite plausible.
If you are a future reader trying to solve the same issue be advised that I have not checked this answer myself.
Thanks!

Comment: Relevant eclipse bug has been filed and discussed: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=263436

Comment: I switched to Sublime for a while, and now I sshfs the remote server into my workspace. Changes apply immediately.

Answer (score 1):

The solution of waiting work for me, but I have another one information.

In the bottom of the screen at the right I can see a little progress-bar with "Querying all". So i think there is really a script behind which is running.

Edit : Two hours after, the progress bar was always at the same state, so waiting wasn't à Solution for me…